# Can't run project spring mvc on localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just create a simple project to demo crud on spring mvc but I can't run it in localhost, please help:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzkaQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJLRx.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMcaY.png)

And this is my structure: [enter image description here][4]

This is file pom:

```
    <artifactId>CustomerManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.14</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>15</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

WebAppInitializer:

```
 

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
         AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            appContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class);
              
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                    "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
            dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Class CustomerController:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        mav.addObject("message", "Heloo Hoapm");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Class Config:

```
@ComponentScan("springmvc")
public class WebMvcConfig {
    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

And the result here is these error

Please help to me. Many thanks

Comment: Your version of java is lower than version which was project compiled by

Comment: @Alex can you show me how to fix ?

Comment: <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>15</release>
                </configuration>
This mean the project is compiled by Java 15. Which Java version you're using to run the application?

Comment: @DucD.Nguyen I see java's version on my computer is 1.8 but when I replace it into file pom.xml, it still didn't work:
I replace part plugins on file pom with this:
<plugins>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>